# Android : File Explorer doesn't show anything

Tags: android

When my android emulator is running, I can use `LogCat` to view log, but when I go to `File Explorer`, I don't see anything. (just blank page). Who know this error, please give me some help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Try going to the Devices window, and choose the device/emulator. IF that doesn't work, try re-starting the adb server.

Comment: When I go to Device, It show a lists of (maybe package) because I have seen my package name in that. But, I don't know what should I do after that. Please tell me

Comment: Select/Highlight the device, and go to File Explorer again.

Comment: Ah, I understand this. GREAT !!! I don't know this before. Thanks very much :D

Comment: @KumarBibek I hope you will answer my post rather than just comment for other people can solve this problem if they met :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try going to the Devices window, and choose the device/emulator. IF that doesn't work, try re-starting the adb server.

Select/Highlight the device, and go to File Explorer again.